# How to get the correct proxy URL in Apigee?

Tags: url, apigee

In my Apigee API Proxy, I need to get the environment URL that is defined in my configuration, so that I can send it as part of the response.

For example: `http://myorg-test.apigee.net/pricing`

However, when I try to get it using `proxy.url`, I get an aliased path, like `http://rrt18apigee.us-ea.4.apigee.com/pricing`

Currently, I'm trying to get it like:

```
var response = {
    proxyUrl : context.getVariable("proxy.url"),
};
```

Comment: How about request.uri?

Comment: @remus request.uri doesn't have the full path. I just see the suffix, like the following example from javascript-cookbook: `/forecastrss?w=12797282`

Comment: Check out the variables list in the Apigee docs - something should be in there

Comment: @remus Yes I tried pretty much all variables from Apigee docs. Some that looked promising like `application.basepath` don't return anything. Perhaps `proxy.url` is simply broken?

Comment: Yeah I'm actually weirded out that the proxy.url isn't working properly. Hmmm

Comment: @remus Should there be a tracking bug for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work around. You can try to get the following variables and create the entire URL

- Get the request scheme (http or https) from  `request.Headers.X-Forwarded-Proto` (if you are using cloud version) or `client.scheme` if you are using on-prem
- Get the host name from `request.host`
- Get the entire request path from `request.path`
- Entire list of URL query params and list from `message.querystring`

You can then construct the entire request URL.

( I know this should not be this painful. Please log a bug in case proxy.url is really broken. )